** <file-name> already exists with <field/value...>. (132) with different records
I get the Error 132 when i try to load data to my DB.
The entries with error's are like "abcß" and "abcss" or "e" and "é".
It looks like Progress handles "ß" like "ss" what couses the error.
What can i do to prevent this?
(Progress 11.7, Codepage 1252, Collation, BASIC)

For some background on what you are running into, see https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-internationalize-applications/page/About-Code-Pages.html

The codepage you have selected has this behavior, it is accent insensitive. Additionally, Progress OpenEdge is case insensitive by default, if you change your field to case-sensitive then you sort of escape the ß to ss dance since, ß becomes SS.
The only real solution going forward is to change your codepage to utf-8, also see Progress Knowledge Base.
Note that this is a major change with all sorts of side effects to be wary of.

At this point urtf-8 is not an option, a workaround would be nice.
Case-sensitive could help with "ß" and "ss" but not with "e" and "é"
